# Android Add button to listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I've two listview when i click first listview item the second listview is loaded. It's fine . After that i've click different item in first listview and back click old item  the second list recreated i know that happened because i've set adapter when the fist listview item clicked . How can i avoid this recreate and load old state. Is it possible or otherwise listview needed to load again . Please help me.

[image: First click]

[image: After first click]

[image: second click]

Comment: Do you want listview to update automatically to an old state which refreshing the adapter?

Comment: So after click on first list item you are set adapter for second listview..isn't it?

Comment: yes Piyush Gutha i've set adapter again any other way to load listview again ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any other way to handle this. I've store values in arraylist. Is it possible to use it again

Comment: yha You can use it again by storing the values at arraylist..

Comment: you can always clear the entries of the arraylist, then add new entries and update the adapter.

Comment: Hey sorry Rohan i think you wrongly understood. I mean look that image that 00:00 is time i've add time here using timepicker and i store that times in an arraylist . How can i reuse this arraylist.

Comment: you can use the same arraylist over and over again, just clear it first and the add new values to it and then do `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`;

Comment: are you updating the second list in the same class or are you using different classes for it?

Comment: then just clear the arraylist on every first listview click. Instead of using a new arraylist for second listview use a global arraylist and clear and update it everytime.

Comment: Did you understand what i am saying? If you found out the problem to your question then i can provide an answer and you can mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether I understood or not the probleb, but if you want to get an backstak effect using the system back button you have to override the onBackPressed method to change the adapter

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {

mAdapter = lastAdapter;

}
```

where mAdapter is the adapter that you are currently using and lastAdapter is the one used for the list before the one you are viewing, but remember to put somewhre the

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

or you will no longer be able to exit the activity even with an empty stak.

Comment: That is not the problem not back button press it's click an item in another listitem.

Comment: make the first adapter final or private of your activity, set the adapter, then when a click occurs use a new adapter with a different name, when you click on your element to get back set your first adapter, you shiud still have it in memory.

Comment: do you have one list view and one activity or are you starting a new activity when clicking?

Comment: same activity look at that picture 2 listview when i click first load second listview

Comment: ok I see now what you want, and as sad by Rohan, it's probably not possible, you could obtain a similar working by using fragments see [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) a good tutorial on how to use fragments.